# Complex derivative of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

If $\psi$ is holomorphic, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bar{\psi}=0$ but I don't know why this is true. I tried something with Cauchy Riemann but that didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure I am confusing? I thought that because of this: the chain rule for complex derivatives is: if $F(\zeta)=f(\phi(\zeta))$, then$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \zeta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\frac{\partial \bar{\phi}}{\partial \zeta}$. Because $\phi$ is holomorphic, we have $\frac{\partial \bar{\phi}} {\partial \zeta}=0$

Comment: Thank you @Anne Bauval

Comment: But the explanation of Bob zorro proves that I was right, I think?

Comment: Yes and I was wrong! I retracted and upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wirtinger derivatives are defined by
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$$

Let $\psi = u + iv$ where $u = \operatorname{Re}\psi$ and $v = \operatorname{Im}\psi$.

Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\overline\psi}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(u-iv) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[(u_x - v_y) - i(u_y + v_x)\right]
\end{align}
Comparing real and imaginary parts, we see that $\frac{\partial\overline\psi}{\partial z} = 0$ if and only if $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$.

But since $\psi$ is holomorphic it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so this is true.

Comment: a big thank you!!! I finally understand :)